# how to debug the .ts file in angular in chrome devtools? webpack didnt build to debug

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to debug the angular project which runs in development mode. But the issue is i cant set breakpoint in .ts file from devtools. i have gone through it that the webpack is didnt displayed in devtools.I am using angular 9.***Some time the webpack is getting build.***[image]

Comment: have your tried  "ctrl +p" then find the file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried but it showing no files found. @JohnVelasquez